# MongoDB in loop get skipped (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Sorry for asking noob question (Below code is associated with express framework and mongoose DB)

I'm trying to loop through the array 'Users' that contains usernames, then I try to match them on mongoose database to get the school and the grade for each user. Then combine them into on final array called UsersInfoFinal .

```
var Users = ['peter', 'john'];
var UsersInfoFinal = [];

for (i = 0; i < Users.length; i++){
    userModel.findOne ({username: Users[i]}, 'username school grade', function (error, UserInfo) {
        UsersInfoFinal .push([UserInfo.username, UserInfo.school, UserInfo.grade]);
    });
}
console.log(UsersInfoFinal );
```

The console should print `[[peter, MIT, 95], [john, Royal Academy, 89]]`, however, the console still prints `[]`, the variable UsersInfoFinal isn't modified.

Why is that? Is there a way to modify the variable after the loop? Help please I'm really new to node.js and MongoDB and have been stuck for hours :S

Thanks!

Comment: `> Why is that?` -- async I/O. Go read some Node tutorial on control flow.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the variable after the loop? Because I'm trying to send the variable somewhere else afterward. `response.render(SomeWebPage, UsersInfoFinal )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will give you a very simple pattern for use in cases like this. Try this code:

```
var Users = ['peter', 'john'];
var UsersInfoFinal = [];

var usersWaiting = 0;

function allDone() {
  console.log(UsersInfoFinal);
}

for (i = 0; i < Users.length; i++){
    usersWaiting++;
    userModel.findOne ({username: Users[i]}, 'username school grade', function (error, UserInfo) {
        usersWaiting--;
        UsersInfoFinal .push([UserInfo.username, UserInfo.school, UserInfo.grade]);
        if (usersWaiting == 0) {
          allDone();
        }
    });
}
```

This is a pretty common pattern for managing multiple asynchronous calls in ecmascript environments. There may be a better way to do it but it sure gets the job done.

Comment: works! What's the magic in it? I mean normally the usersWaiting++ and usersWaiting-- cancel eath other..

Comment: They do cancel each other out. However, the trick is that the code isn't executing in the order you expect it would. Your top level loop is completely executed, then all your callbacks are executed. Checkout this for more info http://book.mixu.net/ch7.html